# Powershell: Selection option in message box

Tags: powershell, automation

I would like to realize this:
I identify different courses from a CSV file in which the user can be registered. Currently, if the user is only registered in one course, it will be directly connected to a remote PC.
But if the user is registered in more than one course on the same day, I want to give the user a choice with the courses he is registered in - and this should be done best in form of a message box (or similar).

This is how I currently display my message box:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($text, $skriptName, 0) | Out-Null
```

Do you have any ideas how I can implement this? Thanks!

Comment: Just get the list of course and send that to Out-GridView for them to select from, then process the selection. No need for message boxes.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Just know the message box is also not really a good choice for arrays or lists, it's a single message thing. That is really OGV in Powershell or using list controls when using forms (WPF or  WinForm) or a datagrid and that's way more work than needed for what you are after.